# boxcar function integral

Tags: calculus

What is the following integral?

$$\int f(x) \, \Pi \left(x, a - \frac{w}{2}, a + \frac{w}{2} \right) dx$$

where $\Pi(x, a - \frac{w}{2},a+ \frac{w}{2})$ is a rectangular pulse centered at $x=a$ with width $w$. I know that if $w$ is sufficiently small, then it approximates a Dirac pulse, and then the integral is known as $f(a)$. But how about this case?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience.

Comment: What is the height of this rectangular pulse? It will only approximate a delta function if it grows in height as it gets narrower.

Comment: The height is some  constant real number h. Lets say h=1.

Comment: What the integral is would depend on $f$.

Comment: If h=1 then the integrand is $f(x)$ if $a-\frac{w}{2}<x<a+\frac{w}{2}$ and 0 otherwise. No?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that if we let $\tilde{f}\!(x) = f(x)\Pi(x,a - w/2,a+w/2),$ $\mathscr{D}$ denote the region where $\Pi$ is nonzero, and $f$ be integrable on $\mathscr{D}$, then
$$
\tilde{f}\!(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
& f(x) & x \in \mathscr{D} \\
& 0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

It seems like it would make sense at first if it was true that
$$
\int \!\tilde{f}\!(x) \, dx = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
& \!\!\int \! f(x) \, dx & x \in \mathscr{D}\\
& 0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
but this equality is generally *not* true. To see this claim, let's rewrite $\Pi(x, \cdot, \cdot)$ as 
$$
\Pi \! \left(x, a - \frac{w}{2}, a + \frac{w}{2} \right) \equiv h \! \left(x - a + \frac{w}{2} \right) - h \! \left(x - a - \frac{w}{2} \right).
$$
Then
$$
\int \!\tilde{f}\!(x) \, dx = \! \int \! f(x) \, h \! \left(x - a + \frac{w}{2} \right) \! dx - \int \! f(x) \, h \! \left(x - a - \frac{w}{2} \right) \! dx.
$$
For $x < a - w/2,$ both integrands are exactly zero and we've so far accumulated zero area under $\tilde{f}\!$. For $x \in \mathscr{D},$ $f$ is integrated normally on the left, and the right integrand is still zero. We've now accumulated some nonzero result from the left integral scanning across $\mathscr{D},$ but the area *previous* was *zero*, so we must begin keeping track of the area *from zero*. For $x > a + w/2,$ both the left and right integrands are again zero, and we're not going to accumulate any more area under $\tilde{f}\!.$ But what's been covered already doesn't just disappear, so we must have that, given
$$
F(x) = \int \! f(x) \, dx, $$
$$
\int \! \tilde{f}\!(x) \, dx =
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&0 & x &< \min\mathscr{D} \\
& F(x) - \lim_{x \downarrow \min \mathscr{D}} F(x) & x &\in \mathscr{D} \\
&\lim_{x \downarrow \max \mathscr{D}} F(x) - \lim_{x \downarrow \min \mathscr{D}} F(x) & x &> \max \mathscr{D}
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$
This argument is simply a continuity argument using the fact that the indefinite integral always comes with a free constant, even when integrating zero.

If we use this continuity, we can rid of the limits and explicitly write, using $\eta = a - w/2$ and $\xi = a + w/2$ as shorthand,
$$
\int \! \tilde{f}\!(x) \, dx = \Big( F(x) - F(\eta) \Big) \, h ( x - \eta) - \Big( F(x) - F(\xi) \Big) \, h( x - \xi).
$$

---

As correctly pointed out, this result may be written as
\begin{align}
\int \tilde{f} \! (x) \, dx &= h(x - \eta) \int_\eta^x f(s) \, ds - h(x - \xi)\int_\xi^x f(s) \, ds \\
&= h(x - \eta) \int_\eta^x f(s) \, ds + h(x - \xi)\int_x^\xi f(s) \, ds.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. The last equation is really a good shorthand.

Comment: I think the last equation can be written as $\int_\eta^x{f(x)} dx h(x-\eta)-\int_\psi^x{f(x)} dx h(x-\psi)$

Comment: Yea you can write it like that too if you'd like. I think I like your expression better; I'll add it in.